# Opensource AMD driver for R5 M330 for Ubuntu 16

Tags: drivers, open-source

my HP Laptop comes with a hybrid graphics - Intel and AMD R5 M330.
I want to install the opensource drivers (which is the only option from what I hear).

I am not able to find the means to install it.

Some help is appreciated.

Comment: They are already installed or your card would not work, they come packaged in to Ubuntu and work out of the box.

Comment: When I am checking  my ubuntu uses the intel card. How to switch between the two cards ?